# Как правильно вытянуть данные с таблицы в интернете?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, парсер

Учу Java,хочу написать типа приложение на телефон. Столкнулся с проблемой. Пытаюсь вытянуть данные с таблицы о курсах валют но в том столбце 4 значения т.е. покупка/продажа и рост/падение показателя по сравнению с предыдущим днем, автоматически я вытаскиваю все 4, но мне нужно только рост и падение. Как правильно это сделать?

```
public class CursApp extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Document doc;
    private Thread sec_thread;
    private Runnable runnable;
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomArrayAdapter adapter;
    private List<ListItemClass> arrayList;
    private Calendar calend;
    private SimpleDateFormat formatter;
    private TextView txt_calendar_vivod;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.currency);
        init();

    }

    private void init(){
        txt_calendar_vivod = findViewById(R.id.calendar_tv);
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
        String date = formatter.format(new Date());
        txt_calendar_vivod.setText(date);


        listView = findViewById(R.id.listview);
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.list_item_currency,arrayList,getLayoutInflater());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getWeb();
            }
        };
        sec_thread = new Thread(runnable);
        sec_thread.start();
      
    }

    private void getWeb(){
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("https://minfin.com.ua/currency/").get();
            Elements tables = doc.getElementsByTag("tbody");
            Element curs_table = tables.get(0);
            Elements rows_curs_table = curs_table.children();
            Element dollar = rows_curs_table.get(0);
            Elements dollar_element = dollar.children();
            Log.d("MyLog","Tbody size " + curs_table.children().get(0).text() );

            for (int i = 0; i <curs_table.children().size() ; i++) {
                ListItemClass items = new ListItemClass();
                items.setData_1(curs_table.children().get(i).child(0).text());
               // items.setData_2(curs_table.children().get(i).child(1).text().substring(0,5).concat(" / ").concat(curs_table.children().get(i).child(1).text().substring(22,27)));
                items.setData_2(curs_table.children().get(i).child(1).text());
                items.setData_3(curs_table.children().get(i).child(2).child(0).text().substring(0,6));
                items.setData_4(curs_table.children().get(i).child(3).text());
                arrayList.add(items);
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
[![На скрине выделено то что мне нужно взять, а под этими данными еще то что вытаскивается автоматом, как избавиться от этого?][1]][1]
```

Comment: у тебя items.setData 4 раза прописано, вот 4 значения и получаешь. И зачем тут цикл?

Comment: Циклом я прохожусь по всем строкам, items.setData вытягивает одно значение из строки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема решила путем изменения команды .text() на команду .ownText(), только вытягивает без разделителя, поэтому писал цикл на поиск пробела в строке и туда установил разделитель